# Which Web Hosting is perfect for Developers?

Tags: web-hosting, vps

I'm a Web Developer and Backend Architect. As a Developer I need Web Hosting to run and deploy my code. Normal Web hosting plans don't offer flexibility, they're focused on simplicity and ease of use for normal/non-tech people. However, I need full stack hosting, a server where I have full control. Where I can install my necessary and preferred software, run my own programs like I do in my own PC. I have seen dedicated hosting, VPS hosting, cloud servers and I don't know which one actually fits my needs.I'll be happy if someone gives me some guidance.

Thank you,
Abraar

Comment: I experienced the same issues and decided on investing in a refurbished server and making my own small server farm in VM's to work on my projects.
Currently using dockers with hopes this changes everything.

Comment: Have a look at AWS, they'll give you full control over everything from server instances to virtual private subnets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use http://aws.amazon.com/pt/ bcz:

1. Price - have *free plans* that help you in development process and paid plans are not expensive
2. Structure - You can configure everything, machine, server configuration, OS, DNS and more.
3. Technologies - Most Hosts have limitations and you cant configure permissions in server. **AWS** use a separated structure that let you set your configurations without limitations.

Well, this is my point. I tested and worked with so many hosts and i realize that **AWS** is the best.

Comment: Your right, AWS is the best! That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

- Dedicated hosting is not necessary because it cost is very high.
- If you need a fixed server eg:4gp ram, 2 core processor and centos.
  you can go for VPS Hosting you can get help in this link [VPS
  Help](https://www.digitalocean.com/).
- If you want to pay for what you use you should go for cloud servers.

Comment: Can I use my terminal (SSH protocol) and connect with my server on a VPS?

Comment: yes you can using putty [link](http://www.putty.org/)